# Material-UI - Is it possible to make the AutoComplete control required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I spent the better part of yesterday trying to make the AutoComplete control required. The API doesn't have a required attribute and onNewRequest doesn't fire if the textbox is blank, onBlur has a bug and doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to hijack handleSubmit (redux-forms-material-ui) to check if that field is empty. Also I put that control in the list of fields to validate but nothing fires for that control. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after writing this question I realized code another developer wrote was stepping on the validation. Nothing is wrong with making the control required field by passing it an error message if the control has no selection.